# How can I understand datagridview sorted or not?

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datagridview

How can I determine if a `DataGridView` is sorted or not? I need to attain a boolen value.

```
If isDgSorted
 -Do something
else
 -Do something
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

### DataGridView.SortOrder Property

*Gets a value indicating whether the items in the DataGridView control are sorted in ascending or descending order, or are not sorted.*

```
Dim Col1 As DataGridViewColumn = DataGridView1.SortedColumn
'If Col1 is null, then the DataGridView is not currently sorted.
```

So your result would look something like this:

```
If DataGridView1.SortedColumn Is Nothing Then
    'Isn't sorted
Else
    'It is sorted
End If
```

For more information, Microsoft explains it more in detail [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sortorder.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Private Sub dataGridView_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView.ColumnHeaderMouseClick
    Select Case e.ColumnIndex
        Case 0
            'handles first column being clicked
        Case 1
            'handles second column being clicked
        Case 3
            'handles third column being clicked and so on
    End Select
End Sub
```